# How can i set an imageview inside dialogfragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, screenshot

I try to take a screenshot and show it with imageview inside dialogfragment,
but I get an error and I don't know how to solve it.

Throws errors in main activity and screenshot class.

Error : E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.hatabildirimi, PID: 9223
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

at com.example.hatabildirimi.ScreenShot.takescreenshotRootView(ScreenShot.java:18)

at com.example.hatabildirimi.MyDialogFragment.onCreateView(MyDialogFragment.java:31)

Thanks for helping :)

> ScreenShot

```
        package com.example.hatabildirimi;
        import android.graphics.Bitmap;
        import android.view.View;
        
        public class ScreenShot {
        
            public static Bitmap takescreenshot(View v){
                v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                v.buildDrawingCache(true);
        
                Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getDrawingCache());
                v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
                return b;
            }
        
            public static Bitmap takescreenshotRootView(View v){
                return  takescreenshot(v.getRootView());
            }
        
        }
```

> DialogFragment

```
    package com.example.hatabildirimi;
    
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDialogFragment;
    
    
    public class MyDialogFragment extends AppCompatDialogFragment {
    
        private ImageView imageView2;
       
    
         private TextView textView2;
        
            @Nullable
            @Override
            public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
                return inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_fragment, container, false);
        
            }
```

> MainActiviy

```
package com.example.hatabildirimi;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button button;
    private ImageView imageView2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        imageView2 = findViewById(R.id.imageView2);


        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MyDialogFragment myDialogFragment = new MyDialogFragment();
                Bitmap b = ScreenShot.takescreenshotRootView(imageView2);
                imageView2.setImageBitmap(b);
                myDialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"My Fragment");

            }
        });

    }
}
```

> activity_main

```
< ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="157dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="162dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="212dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="171dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="198dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="183dp"
        android:text="HELLO"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

> dialog_fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentHolder"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="440dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp">

        </ImageView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:text="Hata Bildirimi Platformu"></TextView>


    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: You calling ` imageView2 = findViewById(R.id.imageView2);` in MainActivity.class so you are trying to find the layout with that id in `R.layout.activity_main` 
But What you want is to set the image in the dialog view , So Pass the image to the dialog Constructor before and set it inside on create (MyDialogFragment .class) before you call .show

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i dont understand can you show me on this code?

Comment: Are you using a `frameLayout` to display the `dialgFragment`? I need to see your `activity_main.xml` layout.

Comment: I add layouts up to code area. activity_main and dialog_fragment.